# Which form is valid between starting with square and curly brackets?

Tags: json, jsonlint

I have two json form. I tried to validate in jsonlint. It show error for first and it validate to second json.

Wrong json:

1. `[ "name": {} ]`

True json:

2. `{ "name": {} }`

Can any one explain why first one is wrong while second one true.

Comment: *can any one differentiate why first one is wrong* Because it doesn't match the spec, besides not meaning anything. If you had used a validator/parser which reports character position information, you would see that the error is reported at the position of the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` starts an *array initializer*. Valid entries are values separated by comments. Example:

```
["one", 2, "three"]
```

`{` starts an *object initializer*. Valid entries are name/value pairs where each pair is a names in double quotes followed by a colon (`:`) followed by any valid value. Examples:

```
{"name": "value"}

{"name": {}}

{"name": ["one", 2, "three"]}
```

All of this is covered by [the website](http://json.org) and [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm).

Your first example is invalid because it's trying to define a name/value pair where a value is expected (in an array entry).

Comment: mean as per yout last line.[ "name": "" ] ,is it valid json?

Comment: @Vasant: No, it is not.

Comment: Didn't DV, but isn't this just a matter of leaving a comment telling the guy to re-read the spec?

Comment: @torazaburo: I thought he needed more explanation than that.